# Object.<anonymous> in named-lazy-chunks-webpack-plugin.js producing a TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null

Tags: angular

i don't know why this error shows up when i run ng serve

```
>     Class extends value undefined is not a function or null
>     TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null
>         at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/IdeaProjects/Test/Frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/plugins/named-lazy-chunks-webpack-plugin.js:9:51)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>         at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>         at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>         at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/IdeaProjects/Test/Frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/common.js:6:44)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>         at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>         at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>         at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OI! You just deleted a question that I was in the middle of answering, and I put in a lot of effort, sooo yea. Here you go.

**Original Question: *The cat leap length in java***

> i'm still new in coding so i get in a lot of trouble can you please
> help me in this simple code. The probleme revolves around a cat's
> leap, each time the cat leaps, the leap length is longer by one. But
> the leap length maximum is 4.The path method displays the leaps done
> by the cat.
>
> {example code was here}

---

If you are going to ask the cat for its path (`cat.path()`) then *of course* the cat needs to **know** it's path. As it is your poor cat keeps leaping around forgetting where its been. What your cat needs is a [**member variable**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) (aka a property or field).

Now there are a lot of ways that you could do this, but I think that this one will be the simplest to understand. There are two things your cat needs to know, it's *"path"* and how far it jumped last.

```
public class Cat()
{
    private string leapPath;

    private string lastLeapLength;
}
```

I notice from the first test that the path should start off as a single `*`, so lets set that in the [**constructor**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) as well as setting the last leap.

```
public class Cat() {
    private string leapPath;

    private string lastLeapLength;

    public Cat() {
        leapPath = "*";
        lastLeapLength = 0;
    }
}
```

Awesome, now your cat is a tiny bit smarter! Now it needs to learn how to leap, but unlike your old, forgetful cat, this new and improved *smart cat* © needs to remember where it's been.

```
public class Cat() {

    ...

    public void leap() {
        int leapLength = lastLeapLength;
        if(leapLength < 4) {
            leapLength++;
            lastLeapLength = leapLength; // the cat remembers how far it leaped
        }

         // the cat figures out where he leaped to
         for(int i = 0; i < leapLength; i++) {
             leapPath = leapPath + ".";
         }

         leapPath = leapPath + "*";
    }
}
```

Now if you ask the cat for his path he can tell you no problem.

```
public class Cat() {

    ...

    public string path() {
        return leapPath;
    }
}
```

Again there are a lot of different ways to solve this problem. Really all the cat needs to know is how many times he leaped, and then he can figure out his path when someone asks him. I encourage you to not just take this answer and to instead implement a different solution.

Stackoverflow is not meant to be a tutorial site, it is really meant for asking specific questions. There are a lot of fantastic sites for learning how to code, and while they won't answer your specific problem for you, they will teach you the basics that you need to figure it out for yourself. Which is always way more fun anyway.

Best of luck and don't get discouraged!

Answer (score 0):

thank you a lot i found where the probleme was , i just needed to install the webpack plugin 
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin --save